# How to determine if X server runs with root privileges

Tags: xorg, root, non-root-user, x-server

This is a one-liner: Is there a way/command to check if the X server is run as root or as user?

---

This was supposed to be a one-liner but alas... I recently upgraded my Arch Linux box. After the upgrade I was notified that `X` now runs rootless. I checked on the official Arch Linux page and it states:

> X is now rootless with the help of systemd-logind [...] [<sup>[1]</sup>](https://www.archlinux.org/)

This got me interested in how to check whether `X` is run rootless or not.  How can this be done?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

There are a few ways to output the user ID (UID) with `ps`; a simple one is with `-f`:

```
ps -fC X
```

Will give you information for all the X servers that are running (there can be more than one).

This presumes that the executable is called `X` -- if there's no such process, you will have to target something else.  Since it almost certainly at least has capital X in it (e.g., `Xorg`, `X11`), an alternative is to filter through grep:

```
ps -o uid,comm -A | grep X
```

This removes the column headers, but the UID is the numerical one on the left.  If this is `0`, then the process is running root.  If nothing turns up, try `ps -fA | grep X`; this one involves more clutter.

Finally, if there is no process with capital `X` in its name, try `x`; you may at least find commands used to control it, such as `startx` or `xinit`.  You could also try `dm`, since display managers usually have this in their name (`gdm`, etc).  However, none of these is actually the X server, and although `xinit` starts the server, the server executable often has [the setuid bit set](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/File_system_permissions#Changing_permission_behavior_with_setuid.2C_setgid.2C_and_sticky_bits), meaning even though `xinit` has a non-privileged UID, *X will still run as root*.

Comment: Hm, `ps -fC X` outputs nothing; `ps X` and `ps -fC startx` do. The `UID` I get is my own just as I expected. But may question may have been imprecise: I'd like to know if X is run rootless or not. I will elaborate on that in my question (trying to be brief it seems I was too brief).

Comment: The `ps X` output is unrelated (see OUTPUT FORMAT CONTROL in `man ps` about that).  I think the X server isn't necessarily called `X`, which might be your problem, but it should at least contain the letter X; I've added a paragraph about using `grep` to get around this.

Comment: Yeah, I'm a bit confused too. The `Arch Linux` page simply states that `X` is now run rootless. Which to my mind seems to imply that it is run by the user. But it would be strange to declare this noteworthy news since `X` seems to be always run by the user. I log into my machine as user and start `X` with `startx`. If my logic is correct then this implies it is always run as a user process and hence rootless. I wonder if there is more to it though.

Comment: Maybe that was my bad.  It seems an odd way to put it to me, but I'll defer to the Arch docs.  I use `startx` as well; on my system hands off to `xinit`, and only the later persists in the process table. The parent process of the X server is `xinit`, so for you it should be `startx`. You find this via the PPID given by `ps -f` once you know the name of the X server process.  Take that PPID number and `ps -p `+ the PPID should give you `startx`.  If none of these things has UID 0, it is "running rootless".

Comment: Nice. I have both processes persisting, `startx` and `xinit`. I check them with `ps -fC startx` and `ps -fC xinit`. Both have a `UID ≠ 0`. One important sidenote: I was only able to find `startx` and `xinit` feeding `grep` a lowercase `x`. You think it advisable to include this in your answer?

Comment: Hmmm -- I've added another paragraph about this.  Neither `xinit` nor `startx` is actually the X server, which is a bit of an issue.  I've asked about this in chat:  http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/26/unix-and-linux  What output do you get for `which X` or `which Xorg`?

Comment: Input: `which X`. Output: `/usr/bin/X`. Input: `which Xorg`. Output: `/usr/bin/Xorg`. I get output for `ps -fC Xorg.bin`. It's path is `/usr/bin/Xorg.bin`. It's `UID` is also different from `0`.

Comment: Okay, that's almost certainly the server then, which doesn't have UID `root`.  Strange the `grep` did not work -- obviously `ps -fA | grep X` would work, I avoided that one because it will include a lot of other clutter.

Comment: I would guess the reason for the separate `Xorg.bin` is to have one *without* the setuid bit set, so that it will run non-root.

Comment: Excellent. Problem solved. Thanks for your patience and effort! I will read up on how this exactly works!