# Xorg with Kernel Mode Settings won't work with other tty

Tags: xorg, tty

Using intel video drivers with kms and i915 on arch linux I haven't been able to start Xorg in a different tty than from the calling one logged as root. By example:

Logged as root on tty1

```
X vt7 :0
```

Freezes the PC and within the Xorg.0.log I see

```
intel(0): failed to set mode: Permission denied [13]
```

In the other hand

Logged as root on tty1

```
X vt1 :0
```

Everything works as usual

I know is not really a serious problem since I still can use Xorg but I'm really intrigued about this behavior for two main reasons

1. permissions for all tty1 ... tty49 are cwr-w----- root tty
2. even if a I'm logged in both tty1 and tty2 with root and try to start X server on tty2 from tty1 it doesn't work as if it only had permission for the calling tty

Does anyone have and idea on what's going on?

Answer (score 3):

You were on the right track. This has indeed something to do with `KMS`. For video drivers that supports `KMS` `X` can be set up to run as a non-root user. You can check if your `X` is run as a non-root user in the way: [How to determine if X server runs with root privileges](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/147409/how-to-determine-if-x-server-runs-with-root-privileges). To strengthen my point, I quote directly from the `Arch Linux` homepage:

"xorg-server 1.16 is now available 2014-07-28

- The new version comes with the following changes:
  X is now rootless with the help of systemd-logind, **this also means that it   must be launched from the same virtual terminal as was used to log in**, redirecting   stderr also breaks rootless login. The old root execution behavior can be restored    through the Xorg.wrap config file (man xorg.wrap). Please note that launching X   through a login-manager (gdm, kdm, ...) doesn't yet provide rootless access.
- The default configuration files are now in /usr/share/X11/xorg.conf.d, all host configurations are still taking place in /etc/X11/xorg.conf ..."

It's generally a good idea to either read the update messages after running `pacman -Syu` or subscribing to the **arch-announce** mailing list which you can do [here](https://mailman.archlinux.org/mailman/listinfo/) and check the website https://www.archlinux.org/ first.